# Using time to increase velocity due to gravity problem (fail to get perfect elasticity)

Tags: math, time, physics, game-physics, gravity

I am just trying to bounce a ball to the same height it was at originally. But as soon as I introduce time, rather than frame, i lose momentum somewhere.

Taking the code down to its bare minimum I have the following:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

float timeDelta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

update(timeDelta);
}

float gravity = -1.0f;
float PosY = 2400;
float VelocityY = 0;

public void update(float timeDelta){

PosY+=VelocityY;
if(PosY<=0){
    VelocityY=Math.abs(VelocityY);
} else{
    VelocityY+=gravity*timeDelta;
}       
Log.d(SystemSingleton.sLogDebug,String.format("Pos: y%f. y%f, timeDelta: %f",PosY, VelocityY, timeDelta));

}
```

Ive left the time delta as milliseconds (rather than dividing by 1000 to give me seconds as you would expect) to make sure I'm not losing anything due to casts or rounding.

If I ignore timeDelta and just apply the entire gravity every frame, this works fine, the peak of its bounce will be exactly 2400 (it's starting position). But taking timedelta into account, it is always less than 2400 and slowly degrades and then every now and again jumps up a significant amount (sometimes way above 2400) before it begins to degrade again.

Ive obviously got something quite drastically wrong but I can't see it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Fix your timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the time step (`timeDelta`) into account when you calculate the new position.  Instead of doing this:

```
PosY += VelocityY;  // no!!
```

Do this:

```
PosY += VelocityY * timeDelta;
```

Even better, do this:

```
PosY += VelocityY * timeDelta + 0.5 * gravity * timeDelta * timeDelta;
```

Also, I would change the bounce detection a little.  Here is some new code to try:

```
// Perform the integration
PosY      += VelocityY * timeDelta + 0.5 * gravity * timeDelta * timeDelta;
VelocityY += gravity * timeDelta;

// Check whether it's time to bounce
if (PosY<=0 && VelocityY<0){
    VelocityY = Math.abs(VelocityY);
}       
Log.d(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float timeDelta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

My guess is this is the cause. Calling currentTimeMillis could give you two different numbers. What I would do:

```
float currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float delta = currentTime - startTime;
startTime = currentTime;
```

Comment: Your way is better, but this is not the main problem.

Comment: Not "the" problem but definitely "a" problem and one I should have seen. Cheers.